# Spacing between navigationBar and tableview cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit, uistoryboard

How can I add a spacing between `navigationBar` and first `UITableViewCell`?

[image]

Comment: Add contentInset to the UItableView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add contentInset to your `UITableView` the first value is for **top** inset the second is **left** third for **bottom** and the last for **right**

**Like this**

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 0, 0, 0) //replace 10 by your needed value
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do it from the cell, but from the tableview:
go to your storyboard where your tableview is, and change the top constraint of your tableview to be something more than the 0 that it currently is.